# Raspberri Pi 4: run an application at startup not working properly in interactive mode

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, bashrc

I wanted to run a script when my RPi 4 boots. my application requires ~./bashrc to run beforehand, then as far as I know, I should call terminal in "interactive" mode.

when I run below command in a terminal, everything is fine. a new terminal is opened and run the program.

```
lxterminal -e "/bin/bash -i '/home/pi/Desktop/myscript.sh'"
```

but when I put it inside /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart with a @ at beginning of line:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@lxterminal -e "/bin/bash -i '/home/pi/Desktop/myscript.sh'"
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
```

when system boots, a freezing terminal is opened, with title of 'bin'. I appreciate it if anyone can give a help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
1) no double quotations.
2) -c flag should be used too.

@lxterminal -e bash -i -c '/home/pi/Desktop/myscript.sh'